# Module warning: Failed to parse sourcemap. (On a NPM package I created)

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, npm-install

Recently I created a NPM package that allows users to handle forms in ReactJS, it has TS support and the index.ts exports some utilities and ReactJS components.

This is the link for my package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-formatge

The package works great and I had no problem whatsoever using it on ReactJS projects, but I get an annoying warning everytime I start the server on other projects:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/react-formatge/dist/esm/index.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from
```

This is the first NPM package that I deploy so I'm a little lost on what's next.

I have stumbled upon with a workaround that involves creating a GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false variable on the .env file. Another workaround would be shutting the warning down whitout the env variable with the following:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        enforce: "pre",
        use: ["source-map-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  ignoreWarnings: [/Failed to parse source map/],
};
```

But of course I don't think shutting the warnings down with workarounds is the best approach.My question is, what do I have to change or fix on my NPM package to avoid this warning when a project installs my package?